# python gspread newbie google spreadsheet

Tags: python, gspread

I have been able to successfully connect to gspread with the appropriate credentials but when I try to open an existig file (in my google account) it fails.  I have tried open() as well as open_by_key(). I am assuming that my account is different than the service account I just created but I don't see how to create a spreadsheet by hand to add (and ultimately read by python).

thanks in advance

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("MyCreds.json", scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
# Does not work (Spreadsheet not found):
wks = gc.open("My Existing Sheet").sheet1
Does not work (Spreadsheet not found):
wks = gc.open_by_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16H7OZohbLmRoe1zZzb5ek5KZnLQKMGA-ZqyfnBms7OI/edit#gid=0").sheet1
# Does not work (Spreadsheet not found):
wks = gc.open_by_key("16H7OZohbLmRoe1zZzb5ek5KZnLQKMGA-ZqyfnBms7OI").sheet1
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I know that the file I am trying to access does exist in my personal account because I can access it in Google sheets.  I created the credentials from my personal account.  Assuming that my credentials are correct, how/where do I go to edit a spreadsheet that I can programatically access?

Comment: So I made a little headway (I think).  Seems that you need to share your personal sheet with the client_email from the json file you got when setting up your credentials.  I shared it, but am still getting the SpreadsheetNotFound exception with all three different open commands.  BTW, I am using the latest API that I got from pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

Comment: I can see you've added an answer to this question. Are you able to open a spreadsheet now?

Comment: Also, you don't need to `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client` to upgrade gspread. This library is not related to gspread. To get latest gspread, do `pip install --upgrade gspread`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do a couple of things to get this to work.

1. get the json object from Google as documented [here](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html).
2. Share the worksheet from your account to the email created in your json object.
3. use the title of the spreadsheet in the `wks = gc.open("My Existing Sheet").sheet1`
    call.

Answer (score 0):

If the library doesn't find the file, the id doesn't exist or the credentials are wrong. 
Furthermore, you should considerate the  use of the official client library with its spreadsheet API v4 (this one is way better than the v3)  :

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation

You should also check that the drive API has been enabled but I guess it is.